# Trying to get an "eraser" working with the HTML5 Canvas and Vaadin, but it just clears

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin and attempting to have a Canvas portion for some simple doodles. I'm using the [CanvasPlus](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/canvas-plus) library for Vaadin in order to accomplish this, and it's working well but I cannot figure out how to make it erase what I've drawn.

When the user clicks down I get the coordinates and begin drawing there:

```
canvas.beginPath();
canvas.moveTo(relativeX, relativeY);
```

And then on the next mouse movement I begin connecting the lines from what they've drawn:

```
canvas.lineTo(relativeX, relativeY);
canvas.setStrokeStyle(color);
canvas.stroke();
```

And [per this answer](http://cssdeck.com/labs/jwvajze4/) when they click erase I call:

```
canvas.setGlobalAlpha(0.0);
canvas.setStrokeStyle(0, 0, 0);
canvas.setGlobalCompositeOperation("copy");
```

But it just clears the whole canvas as soon as I drag, even if I'm nowhere near the previous drawings.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim no knowledge of vaadin, but in general, for composition you should use the `destination-out` mode to clear something existing with what you draw on top.

`copy` will as you discovered just copy, so everything existing will be cleared as 0-bytes are copied over.

Try:

```
canvas.setGlobalCompositeOperation("destination-out");
```